# Redirecting users to different pages after login

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

i have this website and i want to redirect users to 3 different pages, i have created 2 sign up pages that has a hidden field called role with  different values on each of the sign up pages, one being "corporate"..So i used the script below to redirect the user based on the account type he or she creates. Is there a way to add another function to the code i have below that will redirect the user to a 3rd page making it 3 in all? Please any help offered is deeply appreciated

```
if($role === "Corporate"){
        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
        
         echo $welcome = "<script type=\"text/javascript\">
                            swal({
                            title: \"Welcome $username!\",
                            text: \"You're being logged in.\",
                            type: 'success',
                            timer: 3000,
                            showConfirmButton: false });
                            setTimeout(function(){
                                window.location.href = '../Main/index.php';
                            }, 3000);
                        </script>";
    }

   
    else echo $welcome = "<script type=\"text/javascript\">
                            swal({
                            title: \"Welcome $username!\",
                            text: \"You're being logged in.\",
                            type: 'success',
                            timer: 3000,
                            showConfirmButton: false });
                            setTimeout(function(){
                                window.location.href = '../welcome/index.php';
                            }, 3000);
                        </script>";
}
```

Comment: So if i changed the "hidden" value to "corporate" using the browser dev tools, I could backdoor to the corporate page?

Comment: Just use an `else if` after the first `if` then the `else`. You should store the role with the user data in the database so no one can spoof the roles.

Comment: Why don't you just do the redirect server side?

Comment: @ Jay Blanchard , Please can you elaborate more?

Comment: The If else function worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change the code like this:

```
if($role === "Corporate"){
    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
    
     echo $welcome = "<script type=\"text/javascript\">
                        swal({
                        title: \"Welcome $username!\",
                        text: \"You're being logged in.\",
                        type: 'success',
                        timer: 3000,
                        showConfirmButton: false });
                        setTimeout(function(){
                            window.location.href = '../Main/index.php';
                        }, 3000);
                    </script>";
}
else if($role === "ROLE_NAME_HERE") {
     $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
    
     echo $welcome = "<script type=\"text/javascript\">
                        swal({
                        title: \"Welcome $username!\",
                        text: \"You're being logged in.\",
                        type: 'success',
                        timer: 3000,
                        showConfirmButton: false });
                        setTimeout(function(){
                            window.location.href = '../Main/NEW_INDEX.php'; 
                        }, 3000);
                    </script>";
}
else {
   echo $welcome = "<script type=\"text/javascript\">
                        swal({
                        title: \"Welcome $username!\",
                        text: \"You're being logged in.\",
                        type: 'success',
                        timer: 3000,
                        showConfirmButton: false });
                        setTimeout(function(){
                            window.location.href = '../welcome/index.php';
                        }, 3000);
                    </script>";
}
```

or better using DRY rule: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself

```
if ($role === "Corporate") {
    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
    $redirectUri = '../Main/index.php';
} else if ($role === "ROLE_NAME_HERE") {
    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
    $redirectUri = '../Main/NEW_INDEX.php';
} else {
    $redirectUri = '../welcome/index.php';
}

echo $welcome = "<script type=\"text/javascript\">
                        swal({
                        title: \"Welcome $username!\",
                        text: \"You're being logged in.\",
                        type: 'success',
                        timer: 3000,
                        showConfirmButton: false });
                        setTimeout(function(){
                            window.location.href = '$redirectUri';
                        }, 3000);
                    </script>";
```

Comment: That's a lot of needless code repetition when the only difference for each one is the redirect url

Comment: Is it compulsory to use javascript.

Comment: @Ranjusha No please

Comment: // Use below 2 lines of code once user found in db

$_SESSION['username'] = $username;
$msg = "Welcome $username, You're being logged in";

// According to the role, change the location using if else
if($role === "Corporate") {
        
    header("Location:../Main/index.php?msg=$msg");
}       
else if($role === "ROLE_NAME_HERE") {
        
    header("Location:../Main/NEW_INDEX.php?msg=$msg");
}         
else {
 header("Location:../welcome/index.php?msg=$msg");
}

Comment: Thank you, please will try it and get back to you

Comment: @AbrahamAugustusNortey Actually that's Ranjusha's solution I just cleaned it up.

Comment: Appreciate the help given me on this page. Very grateful

Answer (score 0):

I know this question already has an answer but here is a cleaner code and purely PHP alternative.

`$role` and `$username` defined before if statement for testing purpose. It can be removed as your code populates it somewhere else.

```
<?php
$role = "Corporate";
$username = 'Syfer';

if($role === "Corporate"){
        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
        
         echo "Welcome $username! <br> You're being logged in.";
    header( "refresh:3; url=../Main/index.php" );
    }

   
    else {
        echo "Welcome $username! <br> You're being logged in.";
        
        header( "refresh:3; url=../welcome/index.php" );
}

?>
```

Redirect works, tested with PHP 7.2.

Comment: Thank you very much sir